# error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair'

Tags: c++

I want to put two local variable into a pair and return it, this is my code:

```
#include <utility>
class Foo {

};

class Bar {

};

std::pair<Foo, Bar> test() {
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
  return std::make_pair<Foo, Bar>(foo, bar);
}
```

and I got

> ```
> main.cpp:92:10: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair'   
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_pair.h:524:5:
> note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Foo' to 'Foo &&' for 1st argument
>     make_pair(_T1&& __x, _T2&& __y)
> ```

and if I use `return std::make_pair<Foo, Bar>(std::move(foo), std::move(bar));`, the compile will success. So what do I miss?

Comment: When asking questions involving build errors, please include the *full* and *complete* output. There might be informational notes that could contain hints about the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

Because you put explicitly types in template argument lists `<Foo,Bar>`, so type deduction is disabled, and `make_pair` has signature `make_pair(Foo&&, Bar&&).` You are passing Lvalues, Lvalues cannot be bound to Rvalue reference. Don't put types in `<>` or use `pair<Foo,Bar>(foo,bar)`.

Another solution is to rely on type deduction: `make_pair(foo,bar)` then signature is `make_pair(Foo&, Bar&)` and everything works fine.